# Problems with copying files from list via batch file

Tags: batch-file

I get a Text-file from an system - in this file there are filenames (per line one filename) - now with a batch-file every line (filename) from this list should be searched in a directory and copied in an other direcory.

I have this found and it almost works:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "sourceRoot=C:\Users\test\Desktop\COPY_TEST\originale"
set "sourceList=C:\Users\test\Desktop\COPY_TEST\DBLIST.TXT"
set "destFolder=C:\Users\test\Desktop\COPY_TEST\kopiert"

for /f "delim=" %%i in ('dir /a-d /b /s "%sourceRoot%\*.pdf"^|findstr /ig:"%sourceList%"') do (
  copy "%%~i" "%destFolder%\"
)
ECHO "Ausgabe abgeschlossen"
PAUSE
```

This works if the list looks like this:

```
filename1
filename2
....
```

BUT from the other system i get the list like this:

```
filename1;
filename2;
....
```

ANd now i have to edit the search term and add a specific term to them - original:

```
filename1;
```

But it should be searched for:

```
filename1_DE
```

So from the searchterm in the list the last character ";" should be cut and the term "_DE" should be added.
Not the list should be changed only the search term.

Is that possible?

Many thanks!

Comment: Create a copy of your list with trailing semicolons replaced by `_DE` and use that.

Comment: assuming the files have extensions `copy "%%~i" "%destFolder%\%%~ni_DE%%~nxi"`

Comment: @LotPings: that would be a solution but I don't want too much files

Comment: @Gerhard Barnard: i tried your suggestion but now when e.g. "test_02" would be found in the list it copies the file "test_02.pdf" and rename them to "test_02_DEtest_02.pdf". But i want that the name in the list "test_02;"  should not be the search word instead "test_02_DE.pdf" should be found and copied. Thanks!

Comment: my bad, it should have not included `n` in the extension expansion, see answer below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer - i changed my version to following one and it works for me :)

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "sourceRoot=C:\Users\offic\Desktop\COPY_TEST\originale"
set "sourceList=C:\Users\offic\Desktop\COPY_TEST\DBLIST.TXT"
set "destFolder=C:\Users\offic\Desktop\COPY_TEST\kopiert"
set "sprache=_EN"

FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=;" %%i IN ('FINDSTR . "%sourceList%"') DO (
    copy "%sourceRoot%\%%~i%sprache%.pdf" "%destFolder%\"
)

ECHO "Ausgabe abgeschlossen"
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

`for /?` explains expansion on variables, but in short, a file can be broken up into parts expanding on the metavariables. So as example if we have a string of a file:

```
D:\work\file1.txt
```

we can run a `for` loop to get the above string or parts of the string:

```
for %%i in (c:\work\file1.txt) do echo %%i
```

would echo `D:\work\file1.txt`

but we can now expand on `%%i` using things like `d`rive, `p`ath, `n`ame, e`x`tension etc. So a straight forward example would be the below, you can copy it as is and save as a batch file and test it for yourself:

```
@echo off
for %%i in ("c:\work\file1.txt") do (
   echo Full string and retain double quotes: %%i
   echo Full string but remove double quotes: %%~i
   echo Drive only: %%~di
   echo Path only: %%~pi
   echo Filename only: %%~ni
   echo Extension only: %%~xi
   echo Combination of drive and path: %%~dpi
   echo Combination name and extension: %%~nxi
   echo adding text between name %%~ni and extension %%~xi as: %%~niTEXT%%~xi
)
```

So given above explanation, you simply require using name only, add text and join with extension.

```
copy "%%~i" "%destFolder%\%%~ni_DE%%~xi
```